# vue: send changed data to api (axios.put)

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

I have a user account where the user can press the edit-button and edit his user information.
For this I have created two containers with v-if. So if the edit-value is true I render a different div then when the edit-value is false.

Now I have problems saving the updated user information and send the data to my api.
This is a section of my code:

```
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <button
                      @click="savePatient(user)"
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-success float-end"
                    >
                      <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
                      Speichern
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div v-if="userdetails">
                  <div class="form-group row text-left">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label"
                      ><strong>E-Mailadresse </strong>
                    </label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input
                        type="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="email"
                        v-model="userdetails.patient_email"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Here the user can see his actual emailadress (userdetails.patient_email). And he can change it and press afterwards the savePatient-Button. But I don't know how I can give this information to my patient.module.js file and make there a put-call to my api.

My patient.module.js file looks like that:

```
actions: {
edit({ commit }, patient) {
      commit("editPatient", patient);
    },
...

mutations: {
 editPatient(state) {
      return axios
      .put(
        `http://URLv1/patients/${this.id}`,
        (patient_email = user.email),
        (patient_location = user.location),
        (patient_specialties = user.specialty),
        (patient_attributes = user.attribute),
        (patient_languages = user.language),
        (patient_preferred_gender = user.gender)
      )
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a `axios` you only need an action

```js
state: {
   user: {
      email: '',
      location: '',
      specialty: '',
      attribute: '',
      language: '',
      gender: '',
   }
},
actions: {
   editPatient({state, commit}, patient) {
      axios.put(`http://URLv1/patients/${this.id}`, state.user)
   }
}
```

And set the email value linked to this `state.user.email`

```html
              
<button
  @click="editPatient"
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-success float-end"
>
  <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
  Speichern
</button>

...

<div class="form-group">
  <input
    type="email"
    class="form-control"
    id="email"
    v-model="user.email"
  />
</div>

...

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: (state) => state.patient.user,
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("patient", ["editPatient"]),
  },
};
</script>
```